# Is $\frac{cis(a^{\circ})}{cis(b^{\circ})}$ equal to $cis(a^{\circ}-b^{\circ})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Find $\frac{z_1}{z_2}$ in polar form:

$z_1=21\ cis(135^ \circ)$

$z_2=3\ cis(75^ \circ)$

---

One of my friends told me that to solve this problem: "Divide 21 by 3 and subtract 75° from 135°".

So, I was thinking whether mathematically $\frac{cis(a^{\circ})}{cis(b^{\circ})}$ is always equal to $cis(a^{\circ}-b^{\circ})$

If it is yes, why?

If it is not, does his advice work only for this problem?

Comment: $\mathrm{cis} \theta=e^{i \theta}$ Use the euler form to see it clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  $$\displaystyle\text{cis}\left(\alpha^\circ\right)=\text{cis}\left(\frac{\alpha \pi}{180}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{\alpha\pi i}{180}\right)$$

$$\frac{\displaystyle\text{cis}(a^\circ)}{\displaystyle\text{cis}(b^\circ)}=\frac{\exp\left(\frac{a\pi i}{180}\right)}{\exp\left(\frac{b\pi i}{180}\right)}=\exp\left[\frac{(a-b)\pi i}{180}\right]=\text{cis}(a^\circ-b^\circ)$$